# Friction on a weird tricycle

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

I am having trouble on deciding the direction of friction. My teacher told me that the easy way of deciding the direction of friction is to imagine the scene without friction, then see the direction of relative motion and then decide. He gave us a standard example of a cycle. we peddle, the back tire rotates . if there were no friction tire would keep rotating with the point of contact '' going left'' . So the friction on his tire would be on right. Thus pushing the back tire forward and in turn pushing the front tire forward . So the friction on front tire would be towards left. [image]

I am having problem extending this to more than three tires  [image]

My reasoning: If the 1st tire clockwise friction on it must be towards right cause whole bike to accelerate to right. Thus the 3rd tire will translation and rotate . Here I am stuck as translation and rotation are in opposite direction, so I am unable to decide the direction of friction.
Please tell me where I went wrong? And ho does one decide the direction of friction in this case

Comment: Which tires are "driving" tires?  In other words power will be applied to the driving tire(s) to develop the friction that drives the car forward.  The tires that are unpowered will behave like the right tire in your first drawing.

Comment: Wheel 1 & 3 are driving tires

Answer (score 0):

If wheels 1 & 3 are driving, friction might act in either direction depending on whether each wheel is trying to speed up or slow down the vehicle.

You can think of a scenario where one driving wheel is trying to slow down the vehicle and the other speeds it up. Or both are trying to speed up the vehicle, but with different amounts. There is always going to be a push-pull situation between the two driving wheels.

Either way, since the vehicle can only have *one* acceleration (rigid body) it means that driving two wheels means the system is overspecified and more information is needed (or some assumptions) to figure out what happens.

Answer (score 0):

There are three things that can torque on the wheel:

1. Driveshaft accelerating the wheel
2. Rolling friction at the axel or due to deformation of the tire (coefficient of restitution)
3. Static friction at the surface of the tire.

If the object is not accelerating, simply balance those 3 torques. For many physics problems you tend to assume (2) is negligible, but of course in the real world it's there.